# rails/rspec reads render_template method as assert_template 'NoMethodError Exception'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I want to test if my root path renders proper view:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Statics", type: :request do

  describe "GET root path" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get "/"
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end

    it 'routes GET / to static#landing_page' do
      expect('/').to render_template('static#landing_page')
    end
  end

end
```

The second test fails. In order to find out the reasone behind it I type the second command manually with byebug. Then I receive this error message:

> *** NoMethodError Exception: assert_template has been extracted to a gem. To continue using it,
> add `gem 'rails-controller-testing'` to your Gemfile.

For some reasone I am not quite sure rspec confuses render_template with assert_template method and fails. How can I fix it to pass this test?

Answer (score 0):

As [RSpec docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/render-template-matcher) state:

> The render_template matcher is used to specify that a request renders
> a given template or layout. It delegates to assert_template
>
> It is available in controller specs (spec/controllers) and request
> specs (spec/requests).
>
> NOTE: use redirect_to(:action => 'new') for redirects, not
> render_template.

So, no confusion here.